# Duplicate Zeros in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I am solving a array question.

Given a fixed-length integer array **arr**, duplicate each occurrence of zero, shifting the remaining elements to the right.

**Note** that elements beyond the length of the original array are not written. Do the above modifications to the input array in place and do not return anything.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: arr = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0]
Output: [1,0,0,2,3,0,0,4]
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: arr = [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,3]
```

I tried this solution but I am getting wrong output

```
class Solution {
    fun duplicateZeros(arr: IntArray): Unit {
        arr.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
            if(value == 0 && ((arr.size - 1) != index)) {
                arr[index + 1] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[1,0,0,2,3,0,0,4]
```

> **Note** please don't make copy of array. I want to solve in same array. Can someone guide me where is my logic is wrong and how can I fix the problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried the code and some test case is working fine and long one is not working correctly..

```
fun main() {
//    val nums = intArrayOf(1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0)
//    val nums = intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
//    val nums = intArrayOf(8, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7)
    val nums = longTestCase()
    var extraSpace = 0
    var temp = nums.lastIndex
    for (i in nums.indices) {
        if (nums[i] == 0) {
            if (i < nums.lastIndex - extraSpace) {
                extraSpace++
            }
        }
    }
    while (temp >= 0) {
        if (nums[temp - extraSpace] == 0 && extraSpace > 0) {
            nums[temp] = 0
            extraSpace--
            temp--
            if (temp >= 0) {
                nums[temp] = 0
            }
        } else {
            nums[temp] = nums[temp - extraSpace]
        }
        temp--
    }
    nums.forEach { print("$it ") }
}


private fun longTestCase(): IntArray {
    return intArrayOf(
        9,
        9,
        9,
        4,
        8,
        0,
        0,
        3,
        7,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        9,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        5,
        6,
        3,
        1,
        6,
        0,
        0,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        7,
        0,
        3,
        9,
        3,
        6,
        5,
        8,
        9,
        1,
        1,
        3,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        7,
        3,
        3,
        0,
        5,
        7,
        0,
        8,
        1,
        9,
        6,
        3,
        0,
        8,
        8,
        8,
        8,
        0,
        0,
        5,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        3,
        7,
        7,
        7,
        7,
        5,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        8,
        0,
        0
    )
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
[9,9,9,4,8,0,0,0,3,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,5,6,3,1,6,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,7,0,0,3,9,3,6,5,8,9,1,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,7,3,3,0,0,5,7,0,0,8,1,9,6,3,0,0,8,8,8,8,0,0]
```

**Expected output**

```
[9,9,9,4,8,0,0,0,0,3,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,5,6,3,1,6,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,7,0,0,3,9,3,6,5,8,9,1,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,7,3,3,0,0,5,7,0,0,8,1,9,6,3,0,0,8,8,8,8,0]
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by stepping through it statement by statement in a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: At `arr[0]`, the first value, your loop sees a `1` - it does nothing. At `arr[1]`, the second value, it sees a `0`, and sets `arr[2]` to `0` - overwriting the existing `2`. Next it goes to `arr[2]` (the one it just overwrote), sees a `0`, and then overwrites `arr[3]` (a `3`) with `0`. Your loop doesn't insert a new element, it overwrites everything with `0` after the first `0` it sees.

Comment: *"please don't make copy of array"* Why not? Using [a collection builder](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#create-with-collection-builder-functions) would make the logic much more clear. There's a reason why Kotlin encourages immutable data structures - they're usually less buggy.

Comment: so how can we swift the next element when inserting 0 at that place?

Comment: On the first occurrence of 0, you’re writing 0 to the next index you’re going to read while iterating, so it will just push zeroes all the way down. You will need to read the next value before overwriting it.

Comment: Think of it this way - you don't want to *overwrite* the next value, you want to *push* all the remaining values forward one space, to make room for your extra zero. You also don't want to duplicate that newly added zero (otherwise each duplication will cause a duplication and you'll just fill the array with them)

Comment: This task isn't that easy to solve using just a single array. It is doable, but it is probably not the best choice for someone who is still learning. I suggest to start by doing this using two arrays. Also, pick a pen a paper and try to analyze how this transformation behaves, where exactly each item ends.

Comment: Sure i'll try not to duplicate the value and try to shift the values. Thank you guys all

Comment: Oh wow, you got the idea for the linear solution, congratulations :-) I won't verify it for correctness, but yes, this is a very good approach.

Comment: @broot I really appreciate it your kind words :)..

Comment: @Tenfour04 Can you help me on this long test case failure issue?

Comment: @RoarS. I am getting problem in my long test case.

Comment: @vivekmodi: I ran a few tests with your code, and there seems to be issues. It also fails with `1 0 1 0 1`. I made my own version of your code that passes all tests so far, hope this will help finding the bug in your code. Code is in below answer. Good luck! BR

Comment: @vivekmodi; I guess I'm not the only one looking forward to see your final solution. Please share when you get there. BR

Comment: @RoarS. Your answer is best I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because OP found a bug in own code in the question, I made a rewrite of that code with some explanation. Code is using same type of logic, which is copying directly to final position in array opposed to e.g shuffling data one position at a time.

Code is tested with initial test dataset and latest long dataset  provided by OP in the question, and some misc other input/expected pairs. Code is written inside a Kotest.

```
given("do/while approach") {

    forAll(
        row(arrayOf(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), arrayOf(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)),
        row(arrayOf(1, 5, 2, 0, 6, 8, 0, 6, 0), arrayOf(1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 6, 8, 0, 0)),
        row(arrayOf(1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0), arrayOf(1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4)),
    ) { nums, expected ->

        `when`("duplicating") {

            val zeroIndexesToDuplicate = mutableSetOf<Int>()
            var index = 0

            /** find index positions of zeroes to be duplicated */
            /** keep collecting until no more space in rearranged array */
            do {
                if (nums[index] == 0) {
                    zeroIndexesToDuplicate.add(index)
                }
            } while (++index + zeroIndexesToDuplicate.size < nums.lastIndex)

            /** set insertIndex to end of array */
            var insertIndex = nums.lastIndex

            /** set fetchIndex to first item to fetch from */
            var fetchIndex = insertIndex - zeroIndexesToDuplicate.size

            /** when insertIndex catches up with fetchIndex, no more copying is required */
            /** if no zeros, or just a trailing zero, loop is not entered */
            while (fetchIndex in 0 until insertIndex) {
                nums[insertIndex] = nums[fetchIndex]

                /** if copied item is zero to be duplicated, insert an extra zero */
                if (fetchIndex in zeroIndexesToDuplicate) {
                    nums[--insertIndex] = 0
                }

                /** decrement both indexes */
                fetchIndex--
                insertIndex--
            }

            then("result should be as expected") {
                nums shouldBe expected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this testcase `[1,5,2,0,6,8,0,6,0]` your code output is `[1,1,5,2,0,0,6,8,0]` and expected output is `[1,5,2,0,0,6,8,0,0]`.. :(

Comment: @vivekmodi Nice finding! It shows that testing is a must. We'll actually need to know exactly which zeros to duplicate, not only how many. I updated my answer with this bug-fix and more test cases. BR

Answer (score 0):

I would go from right to left, and shift everything right by one step every time I encounter a zero.

Not making copies makes a bit more complicated than needed. If it were a real-world case I would have gone with building a list (copy every item once, and all zero's twice, then take initial list's size elements from newly built list) but I see you are doing this as an excercise

```
class Solution {
    fun duplicateZeros(arr: IntArray): Unit {
        arr.indices
            .reversed()  // because going from left to right will get you endless zero's as soon as you find a zero
            .drop(1) // because the last item will never move to the right, saves logic in [shiftRightFrom]
            .forEach {
                if (arr[it] == 0)
                    arr.shiftRightFrom(it)
        }
    }

    private fun IntArray.shiftRightFrom(index: Int) {
        ((lastIndex) downTo index + 1).forEach {
            this[it] = this[it - 1] // replace value by it's left neighbour
        }
    }
}
```